# Replacing object in an array without state mutation in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to edit an object and replace it in array using React and Redux like this:

```
case EDIT_LANGUAGE:
  let languages = [...state.languageSkills];
  languages[languages.findIndex(el => el.id === action.payload.id)] = action.payload;
  return {
    ...state,
    languageSkills: languages
  };
```

'languages' array looks find before return statement, but state is not re-rendered. I guess I'm mutating state somehow. Other actions (delete, get, set) are working fine. Any tips?

EDIT. This is relevant part of the component that should render

```
import { setLanguages, getLanguages } from '../../actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux"
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {   
    const languageSkillItems = this.props.languageSkills.map((languageSkill) => {
      return (
        <LanguageSkillItem key={languageSkill.id} item={languageSkill} />
      )
    });

    return (
        <div className="profile">            
            <Language languageSkillItems={languageSkillItems} />            
        </div>
    )
    } 
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    languageSkills: state.languageSkills
  };
};


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    ...bindActionCreators({ setLanguages, getLanguages }, dispatch)
  }
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserProfile

);
```

Comment: how payload is created - new object ?

Comment: dashton answer is correct. A basic rule to follow is to avoid mutation in `redux` => Never mutate the state

Comment: I take it `render` is being triggered? what does `<Language />` look like?

Comment: Render was actually not triggered. I've to some refactoring tomorrow, the whole design is pretty... not so good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new array reference, easiest way is just to use `map`, like so:

```
case EDIT_LANGUAGE:
  const languageSkills = state.languageSkills.map(el => {
    if(el.id === action.payload.id) {
        return action.payload;
    }
    return el;
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    languageSkills
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I also need a new array reference. Unfortunately re-rendering is still not working...

Comment: OK, you need to post your code (preferably runnable), it could be many other things. e.g. your react-redux connect logic may not be behaving as you expect because of nesting etc etc.

Comment: I accept this as an answer. My core problem was elsewhere, but answering to your questions lead me to right direction. The application had deeply nested components and one used state which was set in constructor. Thank you.